# How to save HTML file as pdf template using?

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have 2 options for invoice right now in my panel Preview and download as PDF. My preview invoice template works fine but the template of PDF is not copying exact pattern of preview. The following below is my code of preview invoice which is view able in another tab and display all HTML text

```html
<?php
 $countries = config_item('country_list');
?>

<style>
    
    body{
        font-family:Arial;
    }
    table{
        
        font-size:12px;
            width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    table td,   table th, table {
    border-right: 2px solid #333;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
    
}
table.table thead tr th {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
 

</style>
<div class="modal" id="modal-view-invoice" style="    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;     background: #fff;
    padding: 30px;">

<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <?php $logo = get_siteconfig('logo');
  if($logo != ''){
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo base_url().UPLOADSDIR.$logo;?>" width="50%"/>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
     
     <span><h2 style="font-size:40px;    line-height: 0;"><u><?php echo "ALI Usman Printers" ?></u><span style="float:right; font-size:14px">Bill/Cash Memo</span></h2></span>
     <p style="font-size:14px;"><span style="float:right;">P-987/4, SAID PUR ROAD, RAWALPINDI. <b>Ph#: 5550531, Fax#: 5770376</b></span></p>
     <h4  style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 45px;  padding: 0 20px;">M/s: <?php echo $invoice_details['invoice_details']->client_name; ?><br></h4>
     
     <div style=" border-bottom: 2px solid #333; ">
         <div style="    display: inline-block; font-size:16px; width:33%">No. <?php echo $invoice_details['invoice_details']->invoice_number; ?></div>
         
          <div style="display:inline-block; font-size:16px; width:32%; text-align:center;">BILL DATE: <? echo  format_date($invoice_details['invoice_details']->invoice_date_created);?></div>
          
           <div style="display:inline-block; font-size:16px; width:33%; text-align:right">DUE DATE: <? echo  format_date($invoice_details['invoice_details']->invoice_due_date);?></div>
         
     </div>
     
     <table class="table">
 <thead>
   <tr  style="border-bottom: 2px solid #333;" class="table_header" style="">
       <th>S.<br>No.</th>
       <th>QTY</th>
       <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
       <th>D.O.NO.</th>
       <th>DELIVERY<br>DATE</th>
  <th>ORDER<br>NO.</th>
  <th>DATE</th>
  <th>RATE</th>
  <th style="border-right-color: #fff;">RUPEES</th>
  <!-- <th>DESCRIPTION</th> -->
  
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php
 $i=1;
 foreach ($invoice_details['invoice_items'] as $count=>$item)
 {?>
 <tr class="transaction-row">
     <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $item['item_quantity'];?></td>
     <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $item['item_description'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $item['DO'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo format_date($item['DueDate']);?></td>
     <td><?php echo $item['item_order'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo format_date($item['Date']);?></td>
     <td class="text-right"><?php echo format_amount($item['item_price']); ?></td>
 
 <td style="border-right-color: #fff;" class="text-right"><?php echo format_amount($item['item_price']*$item['item_quantity']-$item['item_discount']); ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 $i++;
 }
 ?>
 <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td style="border-right-color: #fff;">&nbsp;</td>
     
 </tr>
 <tr style="border-top: 2px solid #333;">
     <td colspan="9" style="  border-color: #fff;text-align:right; padding: 10px 5px; background: #fff;"><span style="text-align:center; float:left;  padding-top: 30px; "> <hr/> Signature</span><b style="font-size:18px">Total:  <?php echo format_amount($invoice_details['invoice_totals']['item_total'] + $invoice_details['invoice_totals']['tax_total']);?></b></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
     
     
 </div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

This code downloads invoice as PDF.

```html
   @media print{
       
   
    body{
        font-family:Arial;
    }
    table{
        
        font-size:12px;
            width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    table td,   table th, table {
    border-right: 2px solid #333;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
    
}
table.table thead tr th {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
 
#modal-view-invoice{
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;     background: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
}
.h2-1{
    font-size:40px;    line-height: 0;
}
.h2-2{
    font-size:20px;
}
.client-name{
    font-size: 20px; line-height: 45px; border: 2px solid #333; padding: 0 20px;
}
.div-test{
    
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333; 
}
.div-test div{
  display: inline-block; font-size:16px; width:33%;  
}
.div-test div:nth-child(2){
  display:inline-block; font-size:16px; width:32%; text-align:center;
}
.div-test div:nth-child(3){
    display:inline-block; font-size:16px; width:33%; text-align:right
}
}
```

Comment: are you having issue in specific browser or all browsers? Also, you are using `px` in `print` which might not provide proper results.

Comment: @Prajwal i am using chrome to see the invoice  which is viewable as html file. while pdf file is in pdf format

Comment: You need to write separate `css` to adjust for printing. You cannot just copy paste the screen's css.